# How to fix sumarizing leave time and sickness time proportionally and correctly?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datetime, datagridview

**PART 1**

In MySQL database I created "leave" , "Sickness", "Workers", "Orders", "Order_status" tables. The MySQL code which is generated automatically is in below link:

https://pastebin.com/f92RH4id

**PART 2**

In desktop application is concerned I wrote that code which is based on Algorithm which calculates sickness time AND leave time proportionally and the pattern is in below picture:

[image]

And the details of that code are here:

```
   private sick_leaves calculate_sickness_leaves(string NrOrder)
    {
        string query1 = string.Format("SELECT MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE), MAX(order_status.END_DATE) " +
        "FROM project1.order_status INNER JOIN project1.orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER " +
        "WHERE orders.ORDER_NUMBER = '" + NrOrder + "';");

        SQLdata.connection.Open();
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query1, SQLdata.connection))
        {
            using (var reader1 = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader1.Read())
                {
                    date_min = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1[0]);
                    date_max = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1[1]);
                }
            }
        }

        TimeSpan time_of_sickness_to_order = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan time_of_leave_to_order = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);

        for (DateTime date = date_min; date <= date_max; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            long hours_sickness_total = 0;
            long hours_leave_total = 0;
            TimeSpan time_of_all_orders;
            TimeSpan time_of_order;

            string query2 = $"SELECT COUNT(sickness.ID_WORKER) AS 'AMOUNT OF WORKERS ON SICKNESS' " +
            $"FROM project1.sickness WHERE DATE(sickness.BEGIN_DATE) <= '{date}' AND DATE(sickness.END_DATE) >= '{date}';";
            hours_sickness_total = SQLdata.load_amount_sql(query2) * 8;

            string query3 = $"SELECT COUNT(leaves.ID_WORKER) AS 'AMOUNT OF WORKERS ON LEAVE' FROM project1.leaves" +
            $" WHERE DATE(leaves.BEGIN_DATE) <= '{date}' AND DATE(leaves.END_DATE) >= '{date}';";
            hours_leave_total = SQLdata.load_amount_sql(query3) * 8;

            string query4 = $"SELECT IFNULL(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.BEGIN_DATE))), '%H:%i:%s'), '00:00:00') AS 'REALIZATION TIME OF ALL ORDERS IN DAY' " +
            $"FROM project1.order_status INNER JOIN project1.orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER " +
            $"WHERE (DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) = '{date}' AND DATE(order_status.END_DATE) = '{date}');";

            time_of_all_orders = SQLdata.load_time_sql(query4);

            string query5 = $"SELECT IFNULL(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.BEGIN_DATE))), '%H:%i:%s'), '00:00:00') AS 'REALIZATION TIME OF ORDER IN DAY' " +
            $"FROM project1.order_status INNER JOIN project1.orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER " +
            $"WHERE (DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) = '{date}' AND DATE(order_status.END_DATE) = '{ date}') " +
            $"AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = '{NrOrder}';";

            time_of_order = SQLdata.load_time_sql(query5);

            hours_sickness_total = ((long)(time_of_order.TotalSeconds / time_of_all_orders.TotalSeconds) * hours_sickness_total);
            time_of_sickness_to_order += new TimeSpan(hours_sickness_total * 10000000 * 60 * 60);

            hours_leave_total = ((long)(time_of_order.TotalSeconds / time_of_all_orders.TotalSeconds) * hours_leave_total);
            time_of_leave_to_order += new TimeSpan(hours_leave_total * 10000000 * 60 * 60);

        }

        SQLdata.connection.Close();
        sick_leaves x = new sick_leaves();
        x.sickness_time = time_of_sickness_to_order;
        x.leave_time = time_of_leave_to_order;
        return x;         
    }
```

And I had to write additional code to load data of:

1) Time of order which user can select (on each day) `load_time_sql` and time of all orders (on each day too) during the selected order.

2) Total times of sickness time and leave time of each day during the selected order.

```
public static TimeSpan load_time_sql(string query)
{
    TimeSpan x = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, SQLdata.connection))
    {
        using (var reader1 = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                x = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1[0]).TimeOfDay;
            }
            return x;
        }
    }
}

public static int load_amount_sql(string query)
{
    int x = 0;
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, SQLdata.connection))
    {
        using (var reader1 = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                x = Convert.ToInt32(reader1[0]);
            }
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

**PART 3**

Now in this application I'd like to select the "TEST" order. As for as the showing sickness times and leave times of workers in the order and later generating results on the datagridview from "private sick_leaves calculate_sickness_leaves" is written like this in below link:

https://pastebin.com/WUGjTLuv

After generating report of this order i get the results in below:

From MySqlDataAdapter adapter4:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  BEGIN_DATE        | END_DATE              | LEAVE_TIME | 
+---------+---------+---------------+---+-----------+------------+------------+
|  ADAM   |  GAX    | 2019-03-19 7:00:00 | 2019-03-19 15:00:00   | 08:00:00   |        
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+
|  ANDREW |  WORM   | EMPTY              | EMPTY                 | 00:00:00   |
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

From MySqlDataAdapter adapter5:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  BEGIN_DATE        | END_DATE              | SICKNESS_TIME | 
+---------+---------+---------------+---+-----------+------------+---------------+
|  ADAM   |  GAX    | EMPTY              | EMPTY                 | 00:00:00      |        
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  ANDREW |  WORM   | 2019-03-19 7:00:00 | 2019-03-20 15:00:00   | 16:00:00      |
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

from private sick_leaves calculate_sickness_leaves:

```
+----------------+--------------+
| sickness_time  | leave_time   |   
+----------------+--------------+
|  00:00:00      | 00:00:00     |
+----------------+--------------+
```

And as for as the results of sickness_time and leave_time are concerned in my opinion are incorrect. These should be other values than "00:00:00" because i saw the leave by ADAM GAX and sickness by ANDREW WORM. Then the calculation should be correct and calculated proportionally of course.

I have a question: How can I fix this error of summarizing leave time and sickness time proportionally and correctly? Any ideas? Can I count for any help or advice? Thanks in advance.

My codes are in the link to download that or something else:

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/pue5ainu4w4a6ii,r9frx0713s2iy51/shared

Comment: Your question is way too long. Try to reduce it to the relevant parts.

Comment: @juergend I've just edited by reducing question. What about now?

Comment: `int(11)`  ? the `(11)` does nothing without [zerofill](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) .. Also `INT(11)` and `INT` have the same number range the `(11)` does not change that.

Comment: Assuming you are happy with your worker breakdown reports, it looks like the problem lies in your `calculate_sickness_leaves` function. I'd suggest stepping through this function while debugging. In your `hours_x_total calculations`, I'd pay close attention to the variables that would cause these to equal 0 and revisit the relevant queries..

Comment: @Arth did you download these code files which i shared in the link?

Comment: @Prochu1991 Nope, I don’t have a C# environment, my comment was based on the post. To be honest, the question itself is already lengthy without downloading further files.. If you still require assistance, I’d recommend attempting to recreate the issue in a more minimal example. Failing that, a proper debugging process that lets you step through the code line by line is your friend!

Comment: Ok i was reducing this question. Maybe it will be enough.

Comment: Can you provide output of all the queries?

Comment: @EdneyHolder the outputs from all queries are in PART3.

Answer (score 0):

As @Arth had pointed out, the problem is

```
hours_sickness_total = ((long)(time_of_order.TotalSeconds / time_of_all_orders.TotalSeconds) * hours_sickness_total);
```

, more accurately,

```
(long)(time_of_order.TotalSeconds / time_of_all_orders.TotalSeconds)
```

Code snippet [Cast double to long](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dZHAR1) demonstrates the problem.

Perhaps, you could change to

```
var percentage = time_of_order.TotalSeconds / time_of_all_orders.TotalSeconds;
hours_sickness_total = (long) (percentage * hours_sickness_total)
```

Comment: But wait do you mean about writing like this: 
`hours_sickness_total = (long)(time_of_order.TotalSeconds / time_of_all_orders.TotalSeconds)`

Comment: @Prochu1991 that will always be 0. Because `time_of_order.TotalSeconds` is less than `time_of_all_orders.TotalSeconds` in your case.

Comment: Thank you for answer but i've just edited my code and haven't helped yet.

Comment: @Prochu1991 could you show us the value of `time_of_order.TotalSeconds`, the value of `time_of_all_orders.TotalSeconds` and the value of `hours_sickness_total` before `percentage`

Comment: Ok, I checked the values of: `time_of_order.TotalSeconds` = 00:00:00
`time_of_all_orders.TotalSeconds` = 00:00:00
`hours_sickness_total` = 00:00:00 despite of this after `percentage`

Comment: @Prochu1991 then you have to check why your sqlquery of `hours_sickness_total` returns 0.